# Removing cells from table

Tags: html, jquery

I have above example but the problem when i try to remove like Cell C it removes all the cells

I want to remove some tr and leave some. not all

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("td").remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell A <button>Remove Cell A</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell B <button>Remove Cell B</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell C <button>Remove Cell C</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell D <button>Remove Cell D</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i posted to get help so i appreciate if you show me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `$("td")` it, as you've found, selects all the `td` cells on the page.

You need to target that to just the relevant one(s) for the button being pressed; within the button jquery-click handler, the button being pressed is defined as `this` and can be used to find the cell(s) that the button is related to.

Combine with `.closest` to get the cell that the button relates to:

```
$(this).closest("td")
```

Giving:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("td").remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell A <button>Remove Cell A</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell B <button>Remove Cell B</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell C <button>Remove Cell C</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell D <button>Remove Cell D</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you want to remove the whole row (eg if the button is in a different column / td), then you can change `.closest("td")` to `.closest("tr")`.